# How to jQuery for Call div from other website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have questen

how to call div from other website usng javascrpt

i have a page : https://yuyunxp.github.io/share/index.html

then, i wan call `<div id="testa">` in other page

Otherpage.html

```js
jQuery(function($){
  $('#testa').load('https://yuyunxp.github.io/share/index.html');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="testa"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

but i got error page. hehe..

i dont know why page error..

please sir, can u help me.. ?

PS :)

Answer (score 1):

`testa` is an id, then you need to use `#` as selector:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){
 $('#testa').load('https://yuyunxp.github.io/share/index.html');
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="testa"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: oh.. i am forgt.. hehe.. 

this is my homework from my teachr.

ty